# Unable to find the Superset folder in Macbook

Tags: apache-superset

I have Apache Superset installed in my Macbook. I am trying to find the location where this is installed as I want to check the config file. Could anyone assist where Superset is installed in a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Found it to be part of the Anaconda folder. Folder name is "Superset" located at Anaconda3 -> lib -> python 3.6 -> site-packages -> superset

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on how you installed superset if you followed the docs and installed it in a virtual environment it will be in this sub folder for me this was. You probably want to give your virtual environment a better name than `env`..

`/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/envs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/superset`